# How put custom icon to Visio Document for custom ribbon

Tags: vba, visio, ribbonx

I am trying to put custom icon to Visio Document for custom ribbon. When I using Excel I can use utility “Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office”. For example, I can write next xml in utility and insert some picture:

[Custom UI Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXST9.png)

In Excel all working excellent.

But when I trying use this way in Visio, I don’t see picture on ribbon when I opening Visio-document.

After that I opening “Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office” for Visio-document I also don’t see inserted picture that I inserted before.

[Custom UI Editor after opening Visio-document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sLXD.png)

Can anyone help me out with my problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Visio. Custom icons in .vsdx file simply do not work.

If you are really determined to have custom pictures, you should do it otherwise.
 Like via VBA macro, by writing a callback, i.e. instead of `image` specifying `getImage` pointing to some callback function to get the custom image. Or even by creating a full-blown extension.

Note - Microsoft-defined (idMso) images work fine.